# Is $k[x,y]$ isomorphic to a subring of $k[z]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $k$ be a field.  As $k[z]$'s proper ideals are all principal, but $\langle x,y\rangle$ is not, we see $k[x,y] \not\cong k[z]$, however:

> **Question.** Is there a subring $S \leq k[z]$ such that $S \cong k[x,y]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is none - look at the fraction fields.

If there was, then we have $k \subseteq k(x, y) \subseteq k(z),$ but $\mathrm{trdeg}(k(x,y)/k)=2 > 1=\mathrm{trdeg}(k(z)/k)$, which is a contradiction, since transcendence degree is additive on towers (that is, $\mathrm{trdeg}(k(z)/k) = \mathrm{trdeg}(k(x,y)/k)+\mathrm{trdeg}(k(z)/k(x, y))$).

Comment: Elegant. Do you have a reference for (or proof of) $\mathrm{trdeg} (k(z)/k) = 1$?

Comment: @westerbaan By construction, the transcendence degree of $k(z)$ over $k$ is at most $1$.  Are you asking for a reference for why it is not $0$?

Comment: @westerbaan As Erick Wong essentially said, just observe that $\{z\}$ is the transcendence basis (it is algebraically independent over $k$ and... that's basically it, since it obviously generates the field $k(z)$ over $k$).

Comment: It wasn't directly clear to me why $\{p(z),q(z)\}$ could not be a transcendence basis for $k(z)$, but I found the (easy) argument in http://web.stanford.edu/~amwright/TranscDeg.pdf

Comment: @westerbaan Ah, it sounds a little bit like your question was more about whether transcendence degree is well-defined, i.e. do all transcendence bases have the same cardinality?

Comment: Yes, indeed.  But that's clear to me know.  Better reference seems to be http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter6.pdf